# How to stop serving site on a compile error with ng serve

Tags: angular

The default behavior of ng serve is to watch for changes to source code, and recompile when changes are detected. If the application code fails to compile, ng serve will continue presenting the last good build. This can make testing and troubleshooting difficult. Is there a way to use ng serve that will stop serving up the application if the compile fails?

I've searched on Google and in the various github repos' issue lists for angular, and I don't see anyone talking about this.

Here's an example scenario where this could be helpful (among many):

- You have some failing unit tests. You need to make changes and see if they fix the test or not. You make a change, forget a semicolon (or make another compile error), and you see that the test continues to fail, but you miss that the reason the test isn't fixed is because you are still running the same test from the previous attempt due to a compile error.

My hope is that I can determine whether there is an existing way to deal with the issue when developing a local angular application. I'm also interested in whether or not other people are interested in having an option to not serve on a failed compile.

Comment: I should add that I'm also interested to find out if anyone is having this pain, and would like to see a solution...